# A record / CNAME redirect

Tags: dns, subdomain, a-records

How can I set up e.g. when I type www.example.com (so, my domain which I have access) to points to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask (I don't have acces, I just want to redirect there) using **A record** or **CNAME** in my domain name register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of doing this; DNS and HTTP redirect.
If you use DNS, you can only redirect the www.example.com to stackoverflow.com only (not its sub-directories).
Another approach is to create .htaccess in your www.example.com and redirect the page to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask. Please read [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

It seems you need to take the second approach because you want to redirect your users to specific sub-directory.

Comment: Yep, second one is better. Thanks so much